# Fading a portion of Graphics in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, animation, alpha-transparency

I am trying to implement the fade in/fade out animation in swing. 
I am using a JPanel which does not have any components in it. It is completely drawn by paintComponent() method.

Now in one of the portion of this JPanel, I want to implement the fade in/fade-out animation. When I tried using AlphaComposite, the animation is being triggered for whole JPanel.

Can I limit this animation in a small clipped region in that panel?

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
            AlphaComposite.XOR, alpha));
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an Graphics object (like rectangle, circle etc..) for your fade in/out? That way it won't be triggered for the complete panel.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, but that may be more difficult to achieve than what it's worth. Create a `JComponent` of the size you want to animate (or fade), add it to your `JPanel`, and have repaint() called on your smaller component during animation instead of the larger `JPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setClip() before painting to restrict the fading area.
Suppose you want a small fading rectangle. Using Area class create 2 Shapes. Intersection of original clip and fading rect and subtraction (subtract the fading rectangle from the original clip).

Call super.paintComponent() twice with 2 different clips. For the second paint you can set your alpha filter.